# UPSERT for "INSERT INTO tab SELECT * FROM another_tab"

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sql-update, sql-insert

How would I do "UPSERT" (INSERT OR UPDATE) into SQLite table when inserting *multiple rows from another table*.

I've tried:

```sql
INSERT INTO tab_name
SELECT * FROM tmp
ON CONFLICT(id)
    DO UPDATE SET
      val = excluded.val;
```

But it gives me:

> syntax error near "DO"

What would be the correct and the most efficient way to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have hit a documented trap called [parsing ambiguity](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) :

> When the `INSERT` statement to which the `UPSERT` is attached takes its values from a `SELECT` statement, there is a potential parsing ambiguity. The parser might not be able to tell if the `"ON"` keyword is introducing the `UPSERT` or if it is the `ON` clause of a join. To work around this, the `SELECT` statement should always include a `WHERE` clause, even if that `WHERE` clause is just `"WHERE true"`.)

So, does this work better?

```
INSERT INTO tab_name
SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE true
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET val = excluded.val;
```